# Python - appended character gets lost

Tags: python, syntax

Hey I´m quite new to python and i´m writing a script to sort through a file in for some keywords, and everything works fine except a small reading/printing miss that i don´t understand... This is my problem code and the file im scanning through:

```
File:
    SEND TEST
    Tester -> 1FFF 19 02 0F :\user\log
    SEND TEST
    Tester -> 1FFF 18 00 0F [Channel 1] :\user\log
    SEND TEST
    Tester -> 1FFF 12 11 5F :\user\log
    SEND TEST
    Tester -> 1FFF 12 55 1F [Channel 1] :\user\log
    SEND TEST
    Tester -> 1FFF 19 03 2F :\user\log
code:
      if line.startswith('Tester ->'):
         start = 'Tester -> '  # take string from
         end = ':\ ' # end at
         data.append(line[line.find(start) + 9 :line.find(end)].strip('[Channel 1]'))
```

this prints

```
1FFF 19 02 0F
1FFF 18 00 0F [Channel 1]
1FFF 12 11 5F
1FFF 12 55 1F [Channel 1]
1FFF 19 03 2F
```

The `data.append` string has the problem, as shown in the print i works, but i want to extract the code ex `1FFF 12 55 1F` but not `[Channel 1]` aslo... so i used .strip to remove it, but then i get this print:

```
1FFF 19 02 0F
FFF 18 00 0F
1FFF 12 11 5F
FFF 12 55 1F
1FFF 19 03 2F
```

All strings that has `[Channel 1]` loses the first character and if i put a `8` instead of a `9` in `data.apped` it prints:

```
1FFF 19 02 0F
> 1FFF 18 00 0F
1FFF 12 11 5F
> 1FFF 12 55 1F
1FFF 19 03 2F
```

Then it takes the `>` from the `Tester ->` and I don´t understand why? it skips the character in between for some reason? It´s like when I have a `9` it counts every character including spaces and when I have a `8` it counts characters but not including spaces... how is that possible? someone who knows how to fix this, thanks!

```
# Sending Request: Tester -> 1631 11 33 F5 :\ APP_3130 \ Read Identifier \ 
Tester -> 1631 22 F1 2E :\ APP_3138 \ Read Identifier \ 
Tester -> 1FFF 19 02 0F [Channel 1]
```

Comment: I'm not a python programmer but it looks like your ending delimiter is variable: both :\ and [ will signify the end of the string. I think you should look for either one instead of trying to strip out the extra characters after the fact.

Comment: You should read [the docs on `str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: I could suggest [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), but since you're new, this might be too much information - so if you know the length of the string you're looking for, wouldn't `line[line.find(start)+9:line.find(start)+9+14]` do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `strip('chars')` removes all combinations of `'chars'` as noted here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip

So what you're really saying is remove the characters `[, C, h, a, , n, e, l, 1, and ]` from my string.

If you just want to remove `[Channel 1]` I would do the following:

```
import re

line = re.sub(r"\[Channel 1\]$", "", line)
```

This regex pattern will only match the text `[Channel 1]` if it is as the end of the line.

or alternatively if you don't want to include the regex module you could use

```
line = line.replace("[Channel 1]", "")
```

This solution will replace `[Channel 1]` regardless of where it shows up in the line.

=================

The best solution here is to use regex and skip the entire `start` and `end` thing. You can do the following:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"Tester ->\s((?:(?:\w+)+\s)+)(?:\[Channel \d\])?\s?[:]")
if line.startswith('Tester ->'):
    m = pattern.match(line)
    if m is not None:
        data.append(m.group(1).strip())
```

Comment: you could suggest to use `replace('[Channel 1]','')` instead and you'd get my upvote.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha I was just editing it to include that

Comment: If you're going to suggest regular expressions, you might as well rewrite a solution using `re.match`. After all, it is what its meant for - searching text.

Comment: @Kendas why would you use a match to just remove a single thing from the string? That's a lot of extra overhead.

Comment: nitpick: since you're proposing `re`, why not adding `$` since the pattern seems to be in the end: that would be better than `str.replace` then.

Comment: you should explain that the regex removes at the end, whereas replace cannot know that (faster, but less accurate)

Comment: Thank you for the answer replacing .strip with .replace worked, i did not know that you could "replace with nothing", thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @NickChapman I would probably do something like `match = re.match(r'^Tester -> (?P<interesting>.*)(?: \[Channel 1\])? :\', line); if match: data.append(match.group('interesting'))`. But I might be overthinking this...

Comment: @Kendas this guy actually asked a very similar question yesterday about how to use regex to extract the entire thing and that was the answer we've given yesterday. But since this is the method he is going with, this is how to solve the current problem.

Comment: . replace only replaces the last character ']' in [Channel 1] not the whole string?

Comment: @sesar not for me: Input: `>>> "1FFF 12 55 1F [Channel 1]".replace("[Channel 1]", "")` Output: `'1FFF 12 55 1F '`

Comment: 'data.append(line[line.find(start)+2 :line.find(end)].replace("[Channel 1]", ""))' 
prints: '1FFF 19 02 0F [Channel 1' for me...  :((

Comment: @sesar, hold on. If that is what you are doing then I will give you a better way to do this.

Comment: it look much better but i get error... AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' replaced my if-statement with yours

Comment: @sesar updated again, sounds like your data doesn't actually look like what you said it does.

Comment: it actually dose, it repeats with this message and i want the code from every 'Tester ->', put it in at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

this is a version using regex:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('Tester\ ->\ ([0-9a-fA-F\ ]{13})')

for line in file:
    match = rgx.match(line)
    if match:
        data.append(match.group(1))

print(data)
# ['1FFF 19 02 0F', '1FFF 18 00 0F', '1FFF 12 11 5F', 
#  '1FFF 12 55 1F', '1FFF 19 03 2F']
```

the regular expression matches the string `'Tester -> '` followed by a string of length 13 containing hexadecimal characters or spaces.

that is assuming that you iterate over your file line per line.